# XQuery all files under a specific directory?

Tags: xml, xquery

Can I use XQuery to query all XML files under a specific directory?
All the XML files have the same structure.

Also, from what I have seen you can XQuery many files but you need to write 
the names of them in the query. In my case, I need to query 500 XML files with
quite different names each. So Is there a way I can say:

```
for $x in doc("ALL files under a specific directory")/Foo
return $x/Something
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and probably the shortest and most standard solution.

Comment: I wanted to go into subfolders. I found this option for the collection function in the DataDirect web site:   '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use the [`collection()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-collection) function**.

In its **[Saxon implementation](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.html)**, one can use:

```
collection('file:///a/b/c/d?select=*.xml')
```

Comment: Zorba collection documentation [here](http://cf.zorba-xquery.com.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/zorba-0.9.4/zorba/html/collections.html)

Answer (score 1):

For MarkLogic:

```
for $x in cts:search(fn:doc()/Foo, cts:directory-query("/target/directory/"))
return $x/Something
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use the collection() function.
>
> In its Saxon implementation, one can use:
>   collection('file:///a/b/c/d?select=*.xml')

I tried this example under Windows 7 with Saxon HE 9.5.1.5J. The URI then takes a different form, for example:
file:/C:/work/GIT/managedSoftwareDoc/experimenting/xQuery?select=*.xml